# Determining type of parent form in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, types, parent-child

I have a database with table X: let's call it `clients`. I also have a form related to editing table X contents. It may open it on it's own (to browse/edit) as well as from other forms when it is necessary to "pick" a record from table X.

How do I go about telling the parent that a particular `QModelIndex` has been picked straight out of `on_tableView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)` signal handler?

Currently, I had only one "dad" form, so I knew which type of pointer to put in child form (so it can hold a pointer to parent) and just casted a pointer of it's type.

```
if (parent) daddy = qobject_cast<InvoiceEd*>(parent);
```

Now I want to add a call from another form, I realized that I have to cast different pointer out of `QWidget*` pointer, and I don't know how to determine what's "in disguise" under `QWidget* parent` pointer. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using an interface and `dynamic_cast` to pass the information about the selected item:

`InvoiceEdInterface.hpp`:

```
class InvoiceEdInterface {
public:
    virtual void SetSelectedItem (SelectedItemClass i_selected_item) = 0;
};
```

`InvoiceEd.hpp`:

```
class InvoiceEd: public InvoiceEdInterface {
public:
    void SetSelectedItem (SelectedItemClass i_selected_item) override {
        // Process setting selected item.
    }
};
```

`DataForm.hpp`

```
class DataForm {
...
    void on_tableView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index) {
        auto invoice_ed {dynamic_cast< InvoiceEdInterface* >(parent ())};

        if (invoice_ed) {
            invoice_ed->SetSelectedItem (...);
        }
    }
...
};
```

The idea behind the solution is pretty simple: if the parent widget implements the specified interface, that the `SetSelectedItem()` is called. Otherwise, nothing happens.

Note, however, that the proposed solution may not be *Qt-ish*. With Qt, you may add a signal that informs about the selected item. When the `DataForm` object is created in parent widget to select some item, the parent widget should establish a signal-slot connection. This solution is more flexible than the one, proposed above because it lets any object in the program get information about the selected item.

Both of the proposed solution work dynamically without the limitations of the template-based solution.

Comment: If the pointer can be cast to `QObject*` then `qobject_cast` should be a lighter call. At least with older C++ many avoided `dynamic_cast` just because it requires RTTI to be added to executable. Now dynamic cast is more frequently used, though. I guess processors became faster and more memory.

Comment: @AlexanderVX, you are right, `qobject_cast` may also be used to achieve the same result. `dynamic_cast`-based approach is shown for two reasons: 1) I forgot about `qobject_cast`, 2) it may be used not only with QObject-based classes and thus is more general. Another advantage of `dynamic_cast`-based approach is that it does not require is that it does not require you to write any additional code - everything work automatically with the help of RTTI. And I think that RTTI should be avoided only if there are some reasons for it like profiling results or requirement of minimal executable size.

Comment: hello, I made tableView in child form public, and simply connected it's signal to the slot in parent form, right after creating the child form. And it works! So I'll accept your answer because you suggested re-thinking signal-slot connections

Answer (score 2):

There is a code in some existing method implementation to resolve the widget type:

```
// dataform.cpp
void DataForm::myEdit()
{
   ///
   if (parent()) daddy = qobject_cast<InvoiceEd*>(parent());
}
```

and the author wants to make it more flexible e.g. specifically cast to certain widget type depending on the caller. That can be done. Let's pass the desired type to it:

```
class DataForm
{
   public:
   // was void myEdit()
   template <typename T = InvoiceEd> // defaults to InvoiceEd
     void myEdit()
     {
         ///
         T* daddy = qobject_cast<T*>(parent());
         // now we operate with the proper pointer so that
         // exact instance does virtual function calls etc.
     }
///
};

pDataForm->myEdit(); // default case
pDataForm->myEdit<MutatedInvoiceEd>(); // specified case
```

P.S. The above is without criticizing the design which is questionable. In OOP we don't *usually* want to know the context the method was called from or the objects don't want to identify each other. You should in this case create two different methods for different uses or maybe provide an additional parameter (maybe with default value `void myEdit(bool insideOfContainerEdit = true)` so that the code knows about some principal use case. There a number of ways to handle that but we cannot see the entire code of yours.

But of course the very existence of templates in C++ makes us able to solve the problem to degree. I myself find help in templates to sometimes avoid writing more code or derive from the type etc. but overuse of such approach leads to a lot of headache. We ideally should either rely on inheritance with polymorphism or handle such cases entirely via templates with parameter types.

Comment: to me it seems that I can know without a parameter if it was a standalone call, because I have this `QWidget*` pointer in the constructor of the form, and it will be == 0 when it is one. So I just add two templates with two methods in my current class (putting constructor in there to store the pointer and signal handler to call different method from the stored pointer)?

Comment: From design perspective: the less class interface usually the better. But of course the thing should be working.